# Give permission to translate a specific language

Tags: users, i18n-l10n

I want to give an editor the permission to translate only (a) specific language(s).
By default a user can translate content to all available languages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is an awesome module for it... [Translation Management](https://www.drupal.org/project/tmgmt)

> You can specify that a user can only translate from English to Spanish
>   and another user can translate from English to French and you can also
>   have a translation administrator to maintain translation jobs.. And it
>   provides a beautiful interface for it.. There is a [Guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/1445790) for it
>   too..

Answer (score 0):

Download the patch from [HERE](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/permissions_localization.patch).

This patch changes all `hook_perm()` .

```
<?php

  $perms = array(
    'permission internal name' => array(
      'title' => t('Permission title'),
      'description' => t('The permissions does this and that.'),
    ),
}
```

?>

Read the comments for better understanding. Read [Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/313213#comment-1030645).

Comment: While this [link](https://groups.drupal.org/node/11546) may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: why next time? why don't now? I think link only posts are not considered as answers here. :)